# Using java and patterns, while in JSON, replace an entry and key with two entries keeping original key, what pattern to use?

Tags: java, json

I am trying to add a entry that has the same key as another entry in a JSON file using patterns, and tried these patterns...

```
"internalName" : "\Q[\p{Punct}\p{Alpha}]\E",
"internalName" : "([\p{Punct}\p{Alpha}])",
```

To have it where replace from this:

```
"RandomData" : "$1",\n"internalName" : "$1",
```

to this, if the key was Example:

```
"RandomData" : "Example",
"internalName" : "Example",
```

Here is the Java done to replace:

```
JsonText.replaceAll(Pattern, ReplaceWithPattern);
```

What pattern to use for this?

Comment: Is `JsonText` as String? Why don't you use a JSON parser?

Comment: True, but the Json I'm trying to edit have separate childs at some entries. Guess I could try and see.